# sql loaded for decimal numbers is going to warning

Tags: sql-loader

In my csv file i am having decimal number. I am trying to insert data but the concurrent program is going to warning. In the log Error "Record 1: Rejected - Error on table HR_SAL_DATA_TMP, column CHANGE_PERCENTAGE1.
ORA-01722: invalid number". In my control file i have used DECIMAL EXTERNAL but still it is giving the same error. I would be highly obliged If any one helps me out.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and the reason was mismatched data types in the database. Cross-check the data types of your columns and the ones in datafile

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be connected to NLS settings, try this:

```
CHANGE_PERCENTAGE1 "TO_NUMBER (:CHANGE_PERCENTAGE1, '999999999D9', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')",
```